# Loop through dataframe to get strike price closest to share price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, yfinance

I'm trying to loop through the dataframe (example) in order to capture the options' strike that is closest to the current share price of each ticker however I'm not getting that, can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

```
example = {'Ticker': ['A', 'AA', 'AAL','ZM'], 'Current Price': [136, 95, 17,118],'First_exp':['14/04/2022','01/04/2022','01/04/2022','14/04/2022']}

example = pd.DataFrame(example)


strikes =[]
count=0

while count <= len(example['Ticker']):
    try:
        for i in options.get_options_chain(example["Ticker"][count], example["First_exp"][count])['calls']['Strike']:

            if i < example["Current Price"][count]:
                continue
            else:
                strikes.append(i)
                count+=1
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error')
        count+=1
```

Comment: where do you get the share price from?

Comment: @AliSultan in this example yes in the dataframe under 'current price'

Comment: You might want to comment on what the `options.get_options_chain` returns (is this a dataframe? Some other data structure? My guess is this is from the `yfinance` package?). This would make approaching this problem very different. Also, usually it's not wise to loop through a Pandas Dataframe, as it's quite inefficient. There are other ways of doing it such as `groupby` or filtering using lambda functions or other conditions